# Groovy generated constructor missing during compile

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a setup in which I call the generated constructor(@TupleConstructor) of a Groovy class(Product) from a java class(ProductService). The IDE shows the generated constructors and compilation used to work.
But now, for unknown reasons, the compilation fails because the compiler doesnt find the parameterized constructors anymore:

```
ProductService.java:31: error: constructor Product in class Product cannot 
be applied to given types; 
required: no arguments  
found: String,boolean,boolean,float 
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

And this is my current gradle(2.4) setup:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

project.sourceCompatibility = 1.8
project.targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDir 'src/main/java'
...
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.+'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
}
```

Groovy class:

```
@TupleConstructor
class Product {
    String name
    boolean bool1
    boolean bool2
    float price
}
```

Constructor call in Java class(fails to compile):

```
...
products.add(new Product("Parliament", true, false, 10.50F));
...
```

Comment: We'd need to see your code or a small example where you reproduce the behavior.  The Gradle file alone is insufficient information to diagnose your issue.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: There's still some X factor here.  When I make a small project with what you've provided, it compiles fine for me.  Are you compiling from IDE or command line?  Also I assume you've tried running `gradle clean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis:**

This looks to me like a joint compilation issue. Most likely the transform @TupleConstructor runs after Groovy did create the .java stub files, causing the java compilation part to fail. It could have worked before, because you compiled the groovy part independent and then reused existing class files (no clean). Sadly this is a limitation of the stub generator and there is not really a way to fix the issue in Groovy, if the transform is supposed to stay in the same phase.

**Solutions:**

- use the groovy-eclipse batch compiler
- don't use transforms that run after the stub generator
- create a multi module build in gradle, that will compile the groovy part independent

Comment: I think option 1 isnt applicable because of the grade build. Could you give me some links/infos about 'don't use transforms that run after the stub generator'? Im not sure how Id do that at the moment.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I think you were right considering the reused class files, it seems to fit the situation. Groovy-eclipse-compiler unfortunately didnt help, I got the same error from it. I also read up a bit how groovyc works. Its kinda sad, that the groovy stub generation is so broken and doesnt consider/honor  groovy's own ast annotations:(

Comment: The groovy-eclispe batch compiler is standalone and can be used in a gradle build... http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/faster-groovy-compilation-in-intellij-idea-14-1/ suggest that it is used as standard in intellij-idea for gradle based builds already... or did I read wrong? I know it was not really possible in like 2012 with gradle 1.x (1.1 I think) though.

Comment: As for the buggy stub-compiler... sadly this is no bug, but a architecture limitation. Groovy needs typeinformation to apply transforms, but to have that information we usually need the java classes in compiled form. Since we don't have the compiled form before the stub generator has done its work, we are doomed to fail with that approach. Which means another approach is needed

Comment: Hi, thanks for your continued insights, I really appreciate it. As mentioned I already tried the eclipse-groovy-batch in IDEA with no success: "Error:(32, -1) Groovy-Eclipse: The constructor Product(String, boolean, boolean, float) is undefined" "
Also as far as I can tell there is no way to use eclipse-groovy for the gradle build. I read somewhere, that there are no plans for the gradle-groovy plugin  to support it, because it doesnt fit into the build-cycle or something. The only thing I found was a quite dead github project: https://github.com/adammurdoch/gradle-groovy-eclipse-compiler

Comment: Also note that the article you linked only concerns the IDEA build process. Thats not the same as the gradle build process. Im kinda suprised about groovys limitations concerning the AST transformations. Lombok has no issues with that, but I guess thats because Lombok runs during the java compile process and thus maybe has more informations, and groovy doesnt.

Comment: Lombok has to be seen as an extension of the javac compiler. If we had people knowing javac internals enough to produce a 2-way bridge between javac and groovyc, then we could have a better joint compiler without stubs as well. That is the approach of the groovy-eclipse batch compiler uses.