# Constructor of @Immutable class with parameters is not accessible from .java classes

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, abstract-syntax-tree

I clean generated .class files, and re-build my app. If the first call to generated AST constructor happens from a .java class, I get an error. But if I call a constructor generated by an `@Immutable` annotation in a .groovy class first, it becomes visible to .java classes since bytecode is already generated and no errors occur.

So I am wondering how do I set up gradle so it compiles all groovy classes with needed AST transformations *first*, so i can use it from .java classes properly? Also, how do I use `@Builder`-generated code from .java classes, since javac doesn't see any `ClassName.bulder()` method?

1. Here is my .groovy class with ASTT

   ```
   @Immutable class A {
       String a;
   }
   ```
2. Here is how I call its constructor from .java class

   ```
   public class Test {
        A b = new A("321");
   }
   ```
3. And the error I get:

   > Error: "constructor in class [skipped] cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments found: [skipped] reason: actual and
   >   formal argument lists differ in length".

I am using Intellij IDEA 14.4 and Gradle to build.

Comment: Do you have a brief example?

Comment: Create an instance of the class (object) which the constructor has. This will automatically call the constructor.

Comment: What i found is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641790/groovy-generated-constructor-missing-during-compile which seems to be exactly the same

Comment: It seems it is not possible to do this yet with Groovy. See this issue https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7764?attachmentOrder=desc

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once. What worked for me was preventing Java to run before Groovy by setting its source sets in build.gradle to an empty list (see code below).

As far as I understood, this way the Groovy compiler will delegate the Java files to Java, but will do that in the correct order. The Java compile on the other hand will ignore Groovy files, which leads to the unfulfilled dependency you are seeing.

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 11

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = [] // don't compile Java code twice
        }
        groovy {
            srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}

// …
```